# JSON Array Storage Index

Tags: json, sql-server

I would like to be able to store a JSON array in MSSQL column but have an index on it rather than a new table relation.   For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [testId] [bigint] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [testSubIdArray] [nvarchar](max) NULL)
```

Stored in [testSubIdArray] would be [123423,93982,223]

Is there a way to create an index on that?  I only know how to create a virtual column for a single entity like 'customerId' but not array.

Otherwise I have to do it in a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
        [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    [testId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [testSubId] [bigint] NULL)
```

Comment: You can't index a JSON object since order isn't preserved in them. To find a specific element you would need to loop the whole array of objects. It would be best to store them with the ID in the table.

Comment: That is what I thought.   Thank you.